# method is not invoked on p:confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i am using JSF 2.1 primefaces 3.5
i have p:datatable on every row i have edit - delete commandLink, on delete h:commandLink i have used p:confirmDialog when i click delete h:commandLink confirmDialog popup, if i press yes commandButton action method is not invoking..
but if i put p:confirmDialog code out the form method is invoking can't understand what happening

```
<h:body>
<p>hello</p>
<ui:composition template="/template/mastertemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:view>
            <div id="main">
                <div class="full_w" style="height: auto; max-width: 1150px; overflow: hidden;">
                <!--   <div class="full_w" style="height: auto; max-width: 1045px; overflow: hidden;"> -->
                    <div class="h_title"><p class="h_titleParagraph" style="margin: 0px;">Head of accounts</p></div>
                    <h:form styleClass="form" id="headOfAccountsForm">
                     <!--    <p:panel id="analysisTheBudgetPenel" header="Analysis The Budget">  -->
                            <div class="divPanel">
                                <div class="divContent">
                                    <div>
                                        <p:tabView id="headOfAccountsId_tabview">
                                            <p:tab title="Main Head Of Accounts" id="mainHeadOfAccountsId_tab">
<p:dataTable id="allMainHeadOfAccountsId_table" value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMainHeadOfAccountsBean.budgetMainHeadOfAccountsListBean}" var="budgetMainHeadOfAccountsList" rowIndexVar="allMainHeadOfAccounts_rowIndex">

//some columns
<p:column headerText="Edit">
<h:commandLink  id="deleteId_commandLink" value="delete" onclick="confirmation_widgetVar.show(); return false;" />  
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
<p:confirmDialog header="Confirmation"  message="Do you want to delete this row?" widgetVar="confirmation_widgetVar">
                                                         <p:commandButton actionListener="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.deleteMainHeadOfAccountsOnAjax}" value="Yes"  oncomplete="confirmation_widgetVar.hide();">
                                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{budgetMainHeadOfAccountsBean.budgetMainHeadOfAccountIdBean}" value="#{budgetMainHeadOfAccountsList.budgetMainHeadOfAccountIdBean}" />
                                                         </p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmation_widgetVar.hide()" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
// all others closing tags..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to use process attribute like

```
<p:commandButton style="position:absolute;right:-150px;" process="@this"
```

and let me know

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers, especially if you're not sure about the result.

Comment: @bhola yeah. i forgot 'process' attribute well thanks alot :)